# How to sorting using static Array which in Table form in Angular 8

Tags: angular

As you can see in the .ts file that I am trying to do the sorting the Array which is in Table Form. The Array is in Static

**list.component.ts**

```
sort(){
    this.Homes.sort(function(a,b){
      if(a>b)
        return 1
      if(a<b)
        return -1
      return 0;
    });
  }
```

**list.component.html**

```
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" (click)="sort()">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Age</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody *ngFor="let item of Homes">
                    <!-- <tr *ngIf="item.Age < 22"> -->
                    <tr>
                        <td scope="row">{{ item.Name }}</td>
                        <td class={{item.ColorClass}}>{{item.Age}}</td>
                        <td class="fa fa-trash" (click)="delete(item)"></td>
                        <td class="fa fa-pencil" (click)="edit(item)" data-toggle="modal" data- 
                      target="#myModal"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide object property name i.e.

```
sort(){
    this.Homes.sort(function(a,b){
      if(a.Name > b.Name)
        return 1
      if(a.Name < b.Name)
        return -1
      return 0;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on Mukesh Vadodariya response, but simpler

```
sort(){
    this.Homes.sort(function(a,b){
      return a.Name.localCompare(b.Name);
    });
  }
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare